# google app engine soft memory error

Tags: google-app-engine

In google app engine on python, I am getting the following error: exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 157 MB after servicing 2 requests total.
I tried using these following commands to get rid of the problem. context = ndb.get_context() and context.set_cache_policy(False). I put this method in the appengine_config.py and also in the handler that is supposed to handle the request. I was wondering if there is any other place to put this command or if I should be using a different command in total.

Comment: Show us the code that's handling the request.

Comment: Caching isn't the only thing that consumes memory. You may just be fetching too many entities into memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass a function to set_cache_policy https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#policy_functions

```
ctx.set_cache_policy(lambda key: False)
```

Comment: From the same URL: "As a convenience, you can pass True or False instead of a function that always returns the same value. The default policies cache all entities."